# How to define a function so it can be called on the object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, methods

I would like to make a function definition like this:

```
def x(a, b):
    #do stuff
```

But make it callable in such a way:

```
num1=1
num2=2
num1.x(num2)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You are asking to be able to add a new **method** to the built-in `int` type. Python does not support this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you want can only be achieved with **methods** in Python. It's not like C++ where you can define "non-member" methods outside the class (I'm not sure if that's the name for these, but I hope you know what I mean) .

Also Pythons integers (but also floats, strings, etc.) don't support new attributes/methods so the only way to achieve this is by actually subclassing the class or creating a new class:

```
class MyClass(object):  # a custom class
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def x(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.val + other.val)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{self.__class__.__name__}({self.val})'.format(self=self)

>>> n1 = MyClass(1)
>>> n2 = MyClass(2)
>>> n1.x(n2)
MyClass(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do like this to add method. you can use follow below one also :

```
def x(a, b):
    num = a + b
    return num
x = x(1,2)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use classes and within classes define a method named add.
A simple implementation:

```
>>> class integer(int):
...     def __init__(self,n) :
...             self.num = n
...     def add(self,m) :
...             return self.num+m
...
>>> num1 = 1
>>> num2 = 2
>>> num1 + num2
3
>>> num1 = integer(num1)
>>> num1.add(num2)
3
```